# Bootstrap datepicker works only the first time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap datepicker worked only the first time. It did not work from the second time on wards.

```
<script src = "js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

$('#dp1').datepicker()
  .on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var startDate = new Date(ev.date);
    $('#startDate').val($('#dp1').data('date')); //textbox
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

similarly i tired like this

```
$('#dp1').datepicker()
            .on('changeDate', function (ev) {

          var  startDate = new Date(ev.date);
                    $('#startDate').val($('#dp1').data('date'));//textbox


});
```

**check this boostrap datepicker change**

[refer the change event in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/4677/)